# What is mistake in this code in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, filepath

I am getting some error in this code like `"Expected ';' at end of declaration"`. How can I solve this?

```
NSString *imagePath = [[stringPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/"]stringByAppendingFormat:strFilePath];
```

Comment: Don't use `stringByAppendingFormat:` unless the thing at the end is actually a format.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *imagePath = [stringPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFilePath];
```

Your code is missing a closing square brace.  Also stringByAppendingFormat is a heavyweight way to concat (use stringByAppendingString:).  When dealing with paths, save yourself some headache and use the path related methods, which are smart about when to add slashes and so forth.